# over the past seven days, it HAS rained OR over the past seven days it HAD rained

Tags: tense

(1) Over the past seven days, it **has rained** hard. This morning, it was sunny. Tonight, it's snowy.

(2) Over the past seven days, it **had rained** hard. This morning, it was sunny. Tonight, it's snowy.

Some of my friends think the present perfect "has rained" sounds natural. However, my other friends think the past perfect fits better in chronological order. That is, sequentially, the rained happened first, followed the sunshine, and then the snow came last.

Which tense is correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would use present perfect.  You are talking about the weather now, and not about some time in the past. But the past rain is connected to the present. You don't specify the actual time time when it rained, except "at some point in the past week".

There's no particular reason to use the past perfect  There is no point in the past which you are talking about. If you say "It had rained hard last week but yesterday it was sunny" the case for past perfect is stronger, because you are talking about yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

Your other friends are right. The past perfect is correct: before today it **had** rained for days.